# Wrong tableViewCell being returned from UIButton sender

Tags: ios, ipad

For ios 7 and greater part the cell returned is always the first cell i.e. indexpath.row =0. Although I am taking into account of the scrollview inside of the cell with the extra .superview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)getCellforButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    //Check for iOS version and get the cell accordingly
    NSArray *versionComponenets = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ([[versionComponenets objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7)
    {
        // iOS-7 code[current] or greater
        //Additional superview call to account for new scrollview inside of cells
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview;
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS-6 code
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview.superview;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why not have a tag for each button, for e.g button tag = 2 for index path 2 and then get the cell based on the tag using cellForIndexPath:

Comment: I am using a custom cell and so the button is also getting added/deleted dynamically. So tag manipulation will be little complex in this case I believe.

Comment: No it wont be difficult with tag and getting cell from a table as you always need a cell when tapping on a UIButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIView's` `convertPoint:toView` `method` for getting `UITableViewCell`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)getCellforButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint btnPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:yourTableViewHere];
    NSLog(@"btnPositionn : %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(btnPosition));
    NSIndexPath *curIndexPath = [yourTableViewHere indexPathForRowAtPoint:btnPosition];
    id cell = [yourTableViewHere cellForRowAtIndexPath:curIndexPath];
    if (cell)
    {
        UITableViewCell *curCell = cell;
        return curCell;
    }
    else
        return nil
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this line. [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tblLeadForm]; What is the tblLeadForm

Comment: convertPoint provides exact point of UIButton lies on UITableview. My mistake for tblLeadForm as it should be yourTableViewHere